# How to use SIZEOF with a BYTE parameter in assembly?

Tags: assembly, x86, masm, irvine32

EDIT: I am now trying to use Str_length, but it throws an exception when I debug it

I don't know how to use SIZEOF in this case. I know how to use it normally, but I usually use it with an array and not a string. But I thought arrays and strings worked the same

````
INCLUDE Irvine32.inc

.data
myKey      BYTE   "efbcdghijklmnopqrstuvwxyza"
message    BYTE   "the contents of this message will be a mystery.",0
dest       DWORD   -1
.code

main PROC
    ;; inside the MAIN procedure
    push   OFFSET myKey
    push   OFFSET message
    push   OFFSET dest
    call   compute
    ;; message now contains the encrypted string
    mov    edx, OFFSET message
    call   WriteString
    ;; should display "uid bpoudout pg uijt ndttehd xjmm fd e nztudsz."
      
    exit
main ENDP

compute PROC
...
    ; prepare for encrypting or decrypting
    mov     eax, [esp+12]
    mov     ecx, SIZEOF [esp+12]
    mov     esi, OFFSET [esp+12]
    mov     edi, OFFSET outString
    mov     edx, [esp+16]
    cld
...
compute ENDP

END main```
````

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here? Data in memory doesn’t have any size, you choose what size you want to take. There’s also no offsets. So knowing what the code should do would help here

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen I will not have direct access to the string that I need to encrypt/decrypt, so I want to figure out the size so that I can use the size for a loop counter

Comment: You’ll need to give the size as a parameter. There’s no way to know it otherwise.

Comment: please specify the assembler (the tool, masm, tasm, fasm, gas, etc).

Comment: If the string is 0-terminated, you just loop until you see a `0` byte.  (Implicit length, like a  `char*` in C++).  That's what WriteString takes; that's how it knows how many bytes to output even though you only pass it a pointer.  Otherwise as @SamiKuhmonen says, you'd need the length as a parameter along with a pointer (Explicit length, like a `std::string` in C++).